# Prove $\|A\|_2 \le |s|$ if and only if $s^2I-A^TA$ is positive semi-definite where $A \in R^{p \times q}$

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory, singular-values

How to show $\|A\|_2 \le  |s|$ if and only if $s^2I-A^TA$ is positive semi-definite where $A$ is a matrix of $p \times q$?

What I know is $\|A\|_2=\sigma_{max}(A)$, $\sigma_{max}$ is the maximum singular value of A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $A^TA = \sum_{k=1}^q\sigma_k^2 u_ku_k^T$ for an eigendecomposition of $A^TA$.  These $\sigma_k$ are the nonzero singular values of $A$.  Since $s^2I = \sum_{k=1}^q s^2 u_ku_k^T$, the difference is $$s^2I-A^TA = \sum_{k=1}^q(s^2-\sigma_k^2)u_ku_k^T$$ which is PSD if and only if the coefficients $s^2-\sigma_k^2$ are all nonnegative, in particular $\| A\|_2\leq |s|$.

Comment: How to achieve $s^2I = \sum_{k=1}^q s^2 u_ku_k^T$?

Comment: Sorry, But above equality seems unobvious to me.

Comment: Here, $\{u_1,\dots,u_q\}$ are an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^q$, so just like we can expand the identity matrix $I = I_q = \sum_{k=1}^q e_ke_k^T$ where $\{e_1,\dots,e_q\}$ is the standard (orthonormal) basis of $\mathbb{R}^q$, so can we do this with this other orthonormal basis.  If you are still not sure, consider what happens when we compute $Ix$ for $x =  x_1u_1+\cdots+x_qu_q$.  Note that $u_ku_k^Tu_l = \delta_{kl}$ where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta.